# Perl extensions not searched for in @INC?

Tags: perl, urxvt

I'm on Linux, with no root access, and have installed an rpm locally (in `/home/me/local`, rather than `/usr`). This is fine, except that the rpm (`rxvt-unicode`) requires some Perl modules, and the default library search path doesn't include my local directories.

There are two issues, but I can only fix one of them. First off, `/home/me/local/lib64/urxvt` contains `urxvt.pm`. I can fix this by setting `PERL5LIB` to `/home/me/local/lib64/urxvt`, so no problem.

Second, `/home/me/local/lib64/urxvt/perl` contains various extensions (including `/home/me/local/lib64/urxvt/perl/option-popup`). When I run the program (`urxvt`) I now get various messages along the lines of

```
urxvt: perl extension 'option-popup' not found in perl library search path
```

I *can't* fix this by adding the extra directory to `PERL5LIB`. for instance, this:

```
setenv PERL5LIB /home/me/local/lib64/urxvt/perl:/home/me/local/lib64/urxvt
```

makes no difference. I've checked the search path with `perl -V` and it correctly shows both directories. Is there something different about extensions? Don't they check `@INC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rxvt-unicode` looks for its extensions either in a compiled-in directory (which might be something like `/usr/lib64/urxvt/perl` in case of an RPM package, and does not change according to the location of executable files), or in directories specified by the `perl-lib` resource or the `--perl-lib` command line option.

See the relevant part from the **urxvt**(1) man page:

```
   perl-lib: path
       Colon-separated list of additional directories that hold extension
       scripts. When looking for extensions specified by the "perl"
       resource, urxvt will first look in these directories and then in
       /usr/lib64/urxvt/perl/.

       See the urxvtperl(3) manpage.
```

So you need to add something like this to your `~/.Xresources` or `~/.Xdefaults` file:

```
URxvt.perl-lib: /home/me/local/lib64/urxvt/perl
```

---

**Update:** Since rxvt-unicode 9.14 the default extension path includes `$HOME/.urxvt/ext` before the compiled-in system extension directory, therefore you can just place your extension files into `~/.urxvt/ext` instead of setting the `perl-lib` X resource.

In addition to that, rxvt-unicode >= 9.16 looks for Perl extensions in directories listed in the `URXVT_PERL_LIB` environment variable. Now the search order is as follows:

1. Directories listed in the `perl-lib` X resource (multiple directories separated by colons).
2. Directories listed in the `URXVT_PERL_LIB` environment variable (multiple directories separated by colons).
3. `$HOME/.urxvt/ext`
4. `$LIBDIR/perl`, where `$LIBDIR` is the package library directory name compiled into the executable (e.g., `/usr/lib64/urxvt`).

Comment: Can we use an environment variable or ~ in .Xresources?

Comment: No, environment variables are not expanded in the `perl-lib` resource neither by rxvt-unicode nor by xrdb. However, see the updated answer — if you have a recent enough version of rxvt-unicode, you may just place your extensions into `~/.urxvt/ext`, or set `URXVT_PERL_LIB` in a script where you can use values of other environment variables.